# Code works in one Python environments but has a syntax error in another

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I am working on the following code:

```
def numberToName(number):
    if (number==3):
        return "Three"
    elif (number==2):
        return "Two"
    elif (number==1):
        return "One"
    else:
        return "Invalid"

print numberToName(2)
print numberToName(3)
print numberToName(1)
print numberToName(1)
```

This code runs 100% fine in the following online Python environment - http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user11_Hh0KVUpNVP_0.py

But when I use `IDLE` it shows a syntax error `Invalid Syntax` in line `print numberToName(2)`

My Python version is 3.3.1

I have noticed some issues as well. For an example, in the given URL, I can run `print "hello"` and get the output, but the same generated error in IDLE unless I type `print ("Hello")`.

What is the issue here? I am new to Python.

(Please note the main question is about the given code snippet).

Comment: If you plan to learn Python 3.3 (which is a good idea), you're going to want to find an online Python 3.3 interpreter. There are a bunch of them out there if you search. There's even an online [interactive visualizer](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#) that handles 3.3.

Comment: Also, if you don't know which Python version you're using, you can always do this: `import sys; print(sys.version)`. This line of code works with both 3.x and 2.x (and even 1.x, in case you accidentally fall through a Primeval-style temporal anomaly).

Comment: @msw: Wow, that's all kinds of weird. I love their handling of complex numbers—`j` is a legal suffix for numbers, but means nothing. So, e.g., `1+2j` is `3`. Imagine how easy (and useless) trig class would be… And simulating bitwise operators on floats is especially clever; you can prove that `((1 << 64) + 1) & 1) == 0`.

Comment: @msw: No, it is a python environment. It is built by Rice University, specially for their online course in here https://www.coursera.org/course/interactivepython. I am also a student there

Comment: It's a Python-like environment. If you come here and ask why Python is telling you `((1 << 64) + 1) & 1) == 0` and `not dir(dict)` are True, people will waste time trying to figure out that you're running a simulation of Python written in javascript. Clever? Sure. Python? Nope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is  because the IDE is using Python 3.X, and not Python 2.X like in the online environment.

In Python 2.X you can use `print("test")` or `print "Text"`.

In Python 3.x you need to use `print("test")`.

This is because in Python 2.X print is a keyword, and not a function, while in [Python 3 it is a function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function).

If you change the print functions to this, it will run on both the web application and your IDE.

```
print(numberToName(2))
print(numberToName(3))
print(numberToName(1))
print(numberToName(1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, why the other function calling in my code made issues? Please help!

Comment: If you change the print lines to `print(numberToName(2))` it should run in your IDE.

Comment: @Yohan This code will run in both the IDE and the online compiler http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user11_RAR5KMSUd4IHJMq.py

Answer (score 4):

The online environment is Python 2. Your IDLE install is Python 3.

There are many differences, in this case the issue is that `print` is now a function.

See also: http://python3porting.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, why the other function calling in my code made issues? Please help!

Comment: ah I got it, thanks! +1 from me!

Answer (score 3):

The site you link to uses python 2.6 as [they state](http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html).

`print` is no longer a statement in python 3, but rather a function, which means it must be called with parenthesis: `print(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `print 'word'` and `print('word')` was one of the big changes from 2.x to 3.x. To fix it, just treat `print` as a function and it will work.